# Flat Text Import: Field size change

Tags: excel, vba, xla

We have a spreadsheet that imports flat text from a design program.

A file has changed. Now, our program will not import correctly.

Old text file:
[image]

New text file: The Comment field has increased from 17 to 18 characters.
[image]

This is the section of VBA code where I think the selections are made. The file is called CZE_DET.OUT.

```vb
Sub IMPORT_CZEOUT()
    Dim aryJobs() As String
    Dim strComb As String
    Dim strDir As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    Sheets("CEE ORDER").Visible = True
    Sheets("CZE_DET").Visible = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("CEE ORDER").Select
    For i = 1 To colAllBuildings.Count
        strDir = Dir$(colAllBuildings.Item(i) & "\CZE_DET.OUT")
        If strDir <> "" Then
            Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=colAllBuildings.Item(i) & "\CZE_DET.OUT", Origin:=xlWindows, _
                               StartRow:=7, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                               FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 9), Array(5, 1), Array(9, 9), Array(10, 1), _
                               Array(13, 9), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 9), Array(16, 1), Array(18, 1), _
                               Array(28, 9), Array(35, 9), Array(47, 9), Array(54, 1), Array(57, 1), _
                               Array(62, 1), Array(67, 1), Array(72, 1))
            Range("A1:L" & CStr(Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Windows(strShipperName).Activate ' This line does not work, for NO reason!
'            Windows(1).ActivatePrevious
            Sheets("CZE_DET").Select
            Range("A1").Select
            If Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
                ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A12"), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
            Windows("CZE_DET.OUT").Activate
            ActiveWindow.Close
        End If
    Next
```

Entire subroutine here: https://pinnaclestructures365-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/bwolters_pinnaclestructures_com/EpGrxtGx4_BCgL4nl3QDZxcBalaRSL52pI0S8UNX0n6kOg?e=0oyh2k

Comment: Where does `strShipperName` come from?  Your import uses `StartRow:=7` so maybe that skips the headers in any case.

Comment: As a guess I would say that the change in position of the word "Part" does not affect the operation of the input - the key statement is `StartRow:=7,` meaning the first 6 rows of the input are skipped.

Comment: In general your code uses a lot of implicit workbook and worksheet references - you should fix it to make all of those explicit - eg.  `Sheets("CEE ORDER")` should be `someWorkbookReference.Sheets("CEE ORDER")` and `Range("A1")` should be `someWorksheetReference.Range("A1")`   If after using `Workbooks.OpenText` you get a reference to the opened file eg.  `Set srcWb = ActiveWorkbook` and use `srcWb` to refer to that file, then you don't need to rely on Activate/Select.

Comment: As a very quick and dirty (but mission critical) fix I would "pre-process" the input files and cut out the new word "Part" and put it back in the old place. :-) The VBA to do this would be simple.

Comment: I agree with this initial assessment...nothing changed in our code and Row 7 still is the same...so about to answer each question...strShipperName is declared in the Module Import Data, which is the primary import module...the ImportCee's is separate and the only separate import module.......I will make a note to look at the implicit/explicit references. At the moment, I need this working again....and I will modify a newer CZE_DET.OUT file and put the PART back where it was.

Comment: So I moved PART back to where it original was and it still didn't import right...if anyone has time to look, here are the old and newer OUT files... https://pinnaclestructures365-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/bwolters_pinnaclestructures_com/EpGrxtGx4_BCgL4nl3QDZxcBalaRSL52pI0S8UNX0n6kOg?e=0oyh2k

Comment: It doesn't matter where "Part" is, because your code begins the import from Row 7, excluding the headers completely.  What is the specific error you're getting?

Comment: Looks to me like the comment field has increased from 17 to 18 characters.

Comment: Bam...that could be it (the comment field observation)...how can I fix that?

Comment: Review here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.TextToColumns#:~:text=If%20the%20source,as%20listed%20earlier.

Comment: `Array(54, 1)` should be `Array(55, 1)` (and increase each remaining item by 1 after that)

Comment: @TimWilliams that did it! Thank you...I am still in a SOLO IT shop and expected to do it all and dev is my weakest area...going to try to study array's in detail now. And will also ask the software company to let us know when changes like this are made.

Comment: Yes they should be letting you know when they make changes to the file formats...

Comment: Your code is splitting the description field into 4 columns, is that intended or does it not matter ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a re-worked example of how to make your references more explicit.

```vb
Sub IMPORT_CZEOUT()
    Dim aryJobs() As String
    Dim strComb As String
    Dim strDir As String
    Dim i As Integer, cDest As Range
    Dim j As Integer, fName As String, rngData As Range, lRow As Long
    Dim k As Integer, wb As Workbook, wbSrc As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet

    Set wb = Workbooks(strShipperName) 'The wb where data is to be collected
                                       'Include the file extension!
    wb.Sheets("CEE ORDER").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("CZE_DET").Visible = True
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To colAllBuildings.Count
        fName = colAllBuildings.Item(i) & "\CZE_DET.OUT"
        If Len(Dir(fName)) > 0 Then
            Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fName, Origin:=xlWindows, _
                               StartRow:=7, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                               FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 9), Array(5, 1), Array(9, 9), Array(10, 1), _
                               Array(13, 9), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 9), Array(16, 1), Array(18, 1), _
                               Array(28, 9), Array(35, 9), Array(47, 9), Array(54, 1), Array(57, 1), _
                               Array(62, 1), Array(67, 1), Array(72, 1))
            Set wbSrc = ActiveWorkbook      'source data workbook
            Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1) 'source data sheet
            lRow = wsSrc.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            Set rngData = wsSrc.Range("A1:L" & lRow) 'all source data
            With wb.Worksheets("CZE_DET") 'EDIT
                Set cDest = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
            End With
            If Len(cDest.Value) > 0 Then Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1)
            cDest.Resize(rngData.Rows.Count, rngData.Columns.Count).Value = rngData.Value
            'not sure about this line....
            Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A12"), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
            wbSrc.Close savechanges:=False 'close the source file
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

EDIT - as pointed out in a comment, the length of one of the fileds has increased by 1 character, so the `FieldInfo` argument needs to be updated:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fName, Origin:=xlWindows, _
                           StartRow:=7, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                           FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 9), Array(5, 1), Array(9, 9), Array(10, 1), _
                           Array(13, 9), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 9), Array(16, 1), Array(18, 1), _
                           Array(28, 9), Array(35, 9), Array(47, 9), Array(55, 1), Array(58, 1), _
                           Array(63, 1), Array(68, 1), Array(73, 1))
```

Comment: I tried this code but then it fails here... Set cDest = wb.Worksheets("CZE_DET").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

Comment: Try the edit above - if it's still failing then it would be useful to let us know exactly what you see when that happens - do you get an error message?  If Yes, what is the message you get?

Answer (score 1):

The open statement could be simplified as the skipped fields (type=9) are the blanks and values are trimmed on import.

```vb
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=s, Origin:=xlWindows, _
          StartRow:=7, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
          FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 9), Array(4, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(27, 1), _
                           Array(35, 1), Array(54, 1), Array(58, 1),  _ 
                           Array(63, 1), Array(68, 1), Array(73, 1))
```

Tested with this text file

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
ish description   part     punch   comment            qnt feet inch 16th mark
--- ------------- -------- ------- ------------------ --- ---- ---- ---- ------
xxx  8.0x3.5 c 12 8x35c12  psu-psu see drawing ec-1    28  16    8    3  ec-1
xxx  8.0x3.5 c 12 8x35c12  psu-psu see drawing ec-1    28  16    8    3  ec-1
xxx  8.0x3.5 c 12 8x35c12  psu-psu see drawing ec-1    28  16    8    3  ec-1
a-z a-----------z a----- z a-----z a----------------z a-z a--z a--z a--z a----z
```